# wait until something == something in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, sendmessage, content-script

I am writing a script that presses a add to cart button then waits until the cart item count = the current item count

Right now I cant seem to get out of the if statement I added even after the if statement becomes false.

here is what I have attempted:

```
  $("#add-remove-buttons :input")[0].click();
  let cart_count = $("#items-count").text();
  if (cart_count !== `${request} items`){
    setInterval(function() {
      let cart_count = $("#items-count").text();
      console.log(cart_count, `${request} items`);
    }, 50);
  }
  if (cart_count == `${request} items`) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({finished:"done_after1"});
  }
```

This was the result in the console:

[image]
as you can tell it console.logged the 1 items 2 items  then it went to 2 items 2 items  and that is when it is supposed to stop and send the message. But for some reason it kept on console logging

I also tried this code:

```
$("#add-remove-buttons :input")[0].click();
let cart_count = $("#items-count").text();
while (cart_count !== `${request} items`){
  let cart_count = $("#items-count").text();
  console.log(cart_count, `${request} items`);
}
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({finished:"done_after1"});
```

So it was supposed to exit the while loop after the while loop was no longer true. But for some reason when I tested this that page just froze and I couldn't even right click to inspect the console. For some reason the page always freezes when I try this while loop.

If anyone knows whats wrong here I would really appreciate if you could help me out by telling me the problem. Thank You! <3

Comment: `presses a add to cart button then waits until the cart item count = the current item count` - so it should keep pressing add to cart until the numbers match? seems like your code presses the button ONCE only - so if that press doesn't make them match, they never will

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `if` into the `setInterval` - you basically have to execute the script *after* the change happens:

```
$("#add-remove-buttons :input")[0].click();
let cart_count = $("#items-count").text();
if (cart_count !== `${request} items`){
  setInterval(function() {
    let cart_count = $("#items-count").text();
    console.log(cart_count, `${request} items`);
  }, 50);
  if (cart_count == `${request} items`) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({finished:"done_after1"});
  }
}
```

However then don't forget to also use `stopInterval`.

Also using a timer to *wait* for something is not ideal. It would be better to use an event that is triggered when something is changed.

Comment: I put   stopInterval() right above the chrome sendMessage inside the if statement and I still got the infinite loop, maybe it wont == because that car_count is  text and  the request items is a string?

Comment: `stopInterval()` doesn't stop a particular interval, it doesn't stop ANY interval - you need to save the intervalId ... e.g. `let intervalId = setInterval(.....` and then stop it using `stopInterval(intervalId)`

Comment: I also tried   cart_count.toString() and it still wont work. It doesn't seem to even be going into the if statement, could you also edit your answer so I can see were to exactly put that and if it will work

Comment: can you clarify your question? If the above code does not work then you need to post more details about what you're doing

Comment: Also there is no `stopInterval`. It is **`clearInterval`**

Comment: @charlietfl it doesn't matter If I can't even get it to go to the if statement

Answer (score 0):

Since `#items-count` doesn't seem to be an INPUT/TEXTAREA etc (i.e. something you can use the `change` event with, then you can use `MutationObserver` as follows

Note: I'm assuming that

```
$("#add-remove-buttons :input")[0].click();
```

needs to be clicked until the values match - your original code seems to click it once and once only

I'm also using non-jquery for the handling of `#items-count` element - because it's simpler in my opinion

```
function handler(node) {
    let check = first => { // when triggered by mutation event, the argument "first" will be undefined
        let cart_count = node.textContent;
        if (cart_count === `${request} items`) {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({finished:"done_after1"});
            return true; // stop observing
        } else { // didn't match
            if (first) { // this is the first call - add a MutationObserver
                new MutationObserver((mutationList, observer) => {
                    if(check()) { // call with no argument, because MutationObserver is already set up
                        observer.disconnect(); // condition is met, so stop observing
                    }
                }).observe(node, {
                    childList:true
                });
            }
            // condition is not met, so click the add button
            $("#add-remove-buttons :input")[0].click();
        }
        return false; // keep observing
    };
    check(true);
}
handler(document.querySelector('#items-count'));
```

However, if `#items-count` is an element that emits `change` events - it's even simpler

```
function handler(arg) { // when triggered by change event, arg will be defined
    let cart_count = $("#items-count").text();
    if (cart_count === `${request} items`) {
        if (arg) { // trigger by change event
            $("#items-count").off('change', handler);
        }
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({finished:"done_after1"});
    } else {
        if (!arg) { // first call
            $("#items-count").change(handler);
        }
        $("#add-remove-buttons :input")[0].click();
    }
}
handler();
```

Comment: Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: ReferenceError: arg is not defined

Comment: Not part of code in question or answer. So not sure how it relates to anything

Comment: Could I email you my entire file? becuase this doesnt seem to be working my email is wojprod@gmail.com

Comment: Did you just tweet me?

Comment: Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: ReferenceError: handler is not defined//  and maybe ;)

Comment: again, nothing to do with the code in the question or answer

Answer (score 0):

You are not re-checking the value within the interval, so the message only has one chance to be sent, which will happen sometime *before* the interval executes.

Maybe try something more like this...

```
$("#add-remove-buttons :input")[0].click ();
let cart_count = $("#items-count").text ();

if (cart_count === `${request} items`) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage ({ finished: "done_after1" });
} else {
    let interval = setInterval (function () {
        let cart_count = $("#items-count").text ();

        if (cart_count == `${request} items`) {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage ({ finished: "done_after1" });
            clearInterval (interval);
        }

        console.log (cart_count, `${request} items`);
    }, 50);
}
```

Comment: hmm it works but there is just one error for some reason after it gets the url, the cart_count is supposed to update with each url, but for some reason request stays to 2 and when it goes to the 3rd url it is supossed to update to 3 but it just stays at 2 not giving allowing it to do the setInterval

Comment: Your code examples and original post makes no mention of changing URLs, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: may I send you my two files via email? my email is wojprod@gmail.com

Comment: I don't know about that. I think PasteBin or JSFiddle would be better and fairer to the other people helping on this issue.

Comment: Well I have some private code, that I worked really long on and I don't really want to show it all

Comment: How would I do   if  > or == to becuase  >== doesnt work and neiter does >== or >=

Comment: Assuming `cart_count` is a string like "1 items", use `parseInt` to convert it to an actual integer, then compare to `request` using >=, like `if (parseInt (cart_count) >= request) { ... }`. Assuming `request` is also an integer of course, otherwise, you will have to parse it as an integer as well.